# Nested properties with @each in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have this code in SCSS:

```
border: {
    right: 0;
        @each $side in (top, bottom) { 
            #{$side}: {
                left: {
                    radius: 5px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and it compiles to

```
border-right: 0;
top-left-radius: 5px;
bottom-top-left-radius: 5px;
```

This is not the result I expected to see. Is there any way to compile

```
border-right: 0;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
```

with nested properties and @each? I'm using Leafo's scssphp compiler.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  File a bug report with the maintainers of your compiler: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c782373ab556e378b13e

Answer (score -1):

I've just tested this in several environments and your code compiles correctly each time. The issue is probably the version of SASS you're using. I personally use grunt with the latest grunt-contrib-sass version. More info here:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass

Answer (score -1):

Why don't try sass mixin, you can simply do with sass mixin.

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
  border-radius: $radius;
  -moz-border-radius: $radius;
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
}
.radius{
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  @include border-radius(5px 0 0 5px);
}
```

Fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/ywdsnt8k/